# How can I implement Shadow Volumes in WebGL

Tags: webgl, shadow-mapping

I have some questions about drawing shadows of a .obj in a scene of WebGL.
For example, if I want to draw shadows with Shadow Volumes Method, how should I develop this ? I'm trying to implement this but I have failed. Are there more efficient methods to do this (writing less code) ?
Below is the the code:

```
function createShadowBuilder(item) {
var that = function() {};

that.init = function(item) {
    this.item                = item;
    this.glPositionBuffer    = null;
    this.glVertexIndexBuffer = null;
};

that.setupData = function() {
    if (this.glPositionBuffer !== null) {
        gl.deleteBuffer(this.glPositionBuffer);
    }
    if (this.glVertexIndexBuffer !== null) {
        gl.deleteBuffer(this.glVertexIndexBuffer);
    }

    this.glVertices = [];
    this.glIndices  = [];
};

that.addGLVertex = function(vector) {
    this.glVertices.push(vector[0]);
    this.glVertices.push(vector[1]);
    this.glVertices.push(vector[2]);
    this.glIndices.push(this.glIndices.length);
};

that.addShadowSide = function(vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4) {
    this.addGLVertex(vector1);
    this.addGLVertex(vector2);
    this.addGLVertex(vector3);

    this.addGLVertex(vector4);
    this.addGLVertex(vector3);
    this.addGLVertex(vector2);
};

/**
 * Check which triangles face the light source...
**/
that.checkDirection = function(lightLocation) {
    var triangles = this.item.triangles,
        triangle,
        vector,
        i         = triangles.length;

    while (i) {
        i--;

        // Create a normalized vector based on the vector from
        // the center of the triangle to the lights position...
        triangle         = triangles[i];
        vector           = vec3.create(triangle.center);
        vector           = vec3.normalize(vec3.subtract(vector, lightLocation));

        // Compare the vector with the normal of the triangle...
        triangle.visible = (vec3.dot(vector, triangle.normal) < 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Find the edge of the object...
**/
that.findEdge = function() {
    var triangles     = this.item.triangles,
        triangle,
        a, b,
        lines         = this.item.lines,
        line,
        lineSidesHash = {},
        i, j, k;

    this.lineSides = [];

    i = triangles.length;
    while (i) {
        i--;

        triangle = triangles[i];
        if (triangle.visible) {
            j = 3;
            while (j) {
                j--;

                // Check if the side...
                k    = triangle.lines[j];
                line = lines[k];
                a    = line.v1 + '_' + line.v2;
                b    = line.v2 + '_' + line.v1;

                if (lineSidesHash[a] !== undefined) { // Check the v1 -> v2 direction...
                    // The side already exists, remove it...
                    delete(lineSidesHash[a]);
                }
                else if (lineSidesHash[b] !== undefined) { // Check the v2 -> v1 direction...
                    // The side already exists, remove it...
                    delete(lineSidesHash[b]);
                }
                else {
                    // It's a new side, add it to the list...
                    lineSidesHash[a] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert the hash map to an array...
    for (i in lineSidesHash) {
        line = lines[lineSidesHash[i]];
        this.lineSides.push(line);
    }
};

that.rotateVectorX = function(vector, angle) {
    var x, y,
        sin, cos;

    if (angle === 0) {
        return;
    }

    y         = vector[1];
    z         = vector[2];
    sin       = Math.sin(angle);
    cos       = Math.cos(angle);
    vector[1] = y * cos - z * sin;
    vector[2] = y * sin + z * cos;
};

that.rotateVectorY = function(vector, angle) {
    var x, z,
        sin, cos;

    if (angle === 0) {
        return;
    }

    x         = vector[0];
    z         = vector[2];
    sin       = Math.sin(angle);
    cos       = Math.cos(angle);
    vector[0] = z * sin + x * cos;
    vector[2] = z * cos - x * sin;
};

that.rotateVectorZ = function(vector, angle) {
    var x, y,
        sin, cos;

    if (angle === 0) {
        return;
    }

    x         = vector[0];
    y         = vector[1];            
    sin       = Math.sin(angle);
    cos       = Math.cos(angle);
    vector[0] = x * cos - y * sin;
    vector[1] = x * sin + y * cos;
};

/**
 * Update the shadow...
**/
that.update = function(lightLocation, lightAngle, matrix, zoom) {
    // Get the position of the light from the matrix, remove the zoom value...
    var vector = vec3.subtract(vec3.create(lightLocation), [matrix[12], matrix[13], matrix[14] + zoom]),
        sin, cos,
        x, y, z;

    // Instead of rotating the object to face the light at the
    // right angle it's a lot faster to rotate the light in the 
    // reverse direction...
    this.rotateVectorX(vector, -lightAngle[0]);
    this.rotateVectorY(vector, -lightAngle[1]);
    this.rotateVectorZ(vector, -lightAngle[2]);

    // Store the location for later use...
    this.lightLocation = vector;

    this.setupData();              // Reset all lists and buffers...
    this.checkDirection(vector);   // Check which triangles face the light source...
    this.findEdge();               // Find the edge...
};

/**
 * Create the buffers for the shadow volume...
**/
that.createVolume = function(lightLocation) {
    var vertices   = this.item.vertices,
        triangles  = this.item.triangles,
        triangle,
        lineSides  = this.lineSides,
        line,
        vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4,
        i          = lineSides.length,
        j;

    while (i) { // For all edge lines...
        i--;
        line    = lineSides[i];
        vector1 = vertices[line.v1];
        vector2 = vertices[line.v2];

        // Extrude the line away from the light...

        // Get the vector from the light position to the vertex...
        vector3 = vec3.subtract(vector1, lightLocation, vec3.create());

        // Add the normalized vector scaled with the volume
        // depth to the vertex which gives a point on the other
        // side of the object than the light source...
        vector3 = vec3.add(vec3.scale(vec3.normalize(vector3), 30), vector1);

        // And again for the second point on the line...
        vector4 = vec3.subtract(vector2, lightLocation, vec3.create());
        vector4 = vec3.add(vec3.scale(vec3.normalize(vector4), 30), vector2);

        this.addShadowSide(vector1, vector2, vector3, vector4);
    }

    // Add the end caps to the volume...
    i = triangles.length;
    while (i) {
        i--;
        triangle = triangles[i];
        if (triangle.visible) { // Only add polygons facing the light...
            // Add the top...
            j = 3;
            while (j) {
                j--;
                this.addGLVertex(vertices[triangle.vertices[j]]);
            }

            // Add the bottom...
            j = 0;
            while (j < 3) {
                vector1 = vertices[triangle.vertices[j]];
                vector2 = vec3.subtract(vector1, lightLocation, vec3.create());

                this.addGLVertex(vec3.add(vec3.scale(vec3.normalize(vector2), 30), vector1));
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create the vertex position buffer...
    this.glPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.glPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.glVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.glPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;

    // Create the vertex index buffer...
    this.glVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.glVertexIndexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(this.glIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.glVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = this.glIndices.length;
};

that.render = function() {
    // Create the volume for the light...
    this.createVolume(this.lightLocation);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.glPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, this.glPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.glVertexIndexBuffer);
    setMatrixUniforms();

    // Disable the texture coord attribute...
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);
    // Disable the normal attribute...
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);
    // Disable the color attribute...
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

    // Render both front and back facing polygons with different stencil operations...
    gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);                 
    gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);

    // Disable rendering to the color buffer...
    gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false); 
    // Disable z buffer updating...
    gl.depthMask(false);                      
    // Allow all bits in the stencil buffer...
    gl.stencilMask(255);                      

    // Increase the stencil buffer for back facing polygons, set the z pass opperator
    gl.stencilOpSeparate(gl.BACK,  gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.INCR); 
    // Decrease the stencil buffer for front facing polygons, set the z pass opperator
    gl.stencilOpSeparate(gl.FRONT, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.DECR); 

    // Always pass...
    gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 0, 255);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.glVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Enable rendering the the color and depth buffer again...
    gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);
    gl.depthMask(true);

    gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
};

that.init(item);

return that;
```

}

this code is taken from an example on the Web, I'm trying to adapt this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed your English usage and remove superfluous statements.  Please post your code so far.

Comment: not sure if I should close this as a dupe or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232100/shadow-volumes-in-webgl-glsl)